# В представлении не отображается столбцы таблицы при объединении двух моделей в одну?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Имеется две таблицы Jourgrpredmet, Kontingents. Соединяюсь и работаю через linq to sql.
В одном представлении понадобился отобразить данные сразу из двух таблиц. Две модели которые мне создал Linq объединил в один "Jmodel"
в контроллере пишу

```
public ActionResult JOpen (string id)
{
        var kont = dbkont.Kontingents.Where(g => g.GRUPPA == Session["seljourgr"]).ToList();
        return View(kont);
}
```

Модель:

```
 public class Jmodel
    {
     public IEnumerable<WebApplication11.Models.Kontingents> kont { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<WebApplication11.Models.Jourgrpredmet> jourpr { get; set; }
    }
```

В представлении:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication11.Models.Jmodel>
@foreach (var v in Model)
                  {
               @v.jourpr
                  }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              @foreach (WebApplication11.Models.Jmodel k in Model)
                {<tr>
<td>@k.kontingent.FAM @k.kontingent.IM @k.kontingent.OTC</td>
                    </tr>}
```

> Когда пишу  @v.jourpr не отображаются столбцы таблицы. На второй таблице тоже нет столбцов @k.kontingent.FAM. "FAM" подчеркнут красным
>   Если изменить модель

```
public class Jmodel
        {
         public Kontingents> kont { get; set; }
            public Jourgrpredmet> jourpr { get; set; }
        }
```

> Все столбцы отображаются, выбираются но при выполнении приложения ошибка, так как требуется тип GetEnumerable так как в контроллере во вью я передаю ToList();

Comment: поправьте код и маркап в вопросе - это не скомпилируется

Answer (score 0):

```
<table><tbody>
@foreach (var v in Model.jourpr)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@v.Name</td>
  </tr>
}
</tbody></table>

<table><tbody>
@foreach (var k in Model.kont)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@k.FAM @k.IM @k.OTC</td>
  </tr>
}
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Ошибка во время компиляции ресурса
Сообщение об ошибке компилятора: CS1061: 'IEnumerable<Jmodel>' does not contain a definition for 'jourpr' and no extension method 'jourpr' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Jmodel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @foreach (var k in Model.kont). Model.kont ничего не выходит, ошибка. это я не правильно делаю или VS?

Comment: @Pupkin поправьте код и маркап в вопросе